# Twilio Outbound SMS Message Not Delivered

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm using the following code to send an outbound SMS message from Twilio:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = '<ACCOUNT SID>'
auth_token  = '<AUTH TOKEN>'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(to='<To mobile number>',
                                 from_='<Twilio phone number>',
                                 body='Stackoverflow is awesome!')

print('Message ID: ' + message.sid)
```

The code worked fine for my mobile number i.e. the messages are received on my phone and the Programmable Messaging Log shows the status **Delivered**. All good!

However, some of my friends/colleagues couldn't receive messages on their phones. When I checked the Programmable Messaging Logs, it shows the status **Sent** (and not **Delivered**). I couldn't figure out the possible issue and a working solution to this problem.

Any guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm, were those numbers added to your twilio account?

Comment: Yes @BhagyeshDudhediya! I have added those numbers in the Verified Caller IDs list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved.

The **Sent** status of the messages that were not delivered eventually turned to **Undelivered (Error: 30008) Unknown error**. I went through [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008) page and read about possible solutions to resolve Error 30008. Eventually, I figured out that I was using an exclamation mark (`!`) in the `body` text that was causing the problem. I removed the exclamation mark and the SMS was delivered successfully.